# Rearrange Cells to Find Optimized Outcome

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code using VBA in excel to help with scheduling of process flow of parts through equipment . Currently once  a part number is put in the rest of the row populates with the time in each equipment. After a second part number is put into the second row , the times are populated when that process should start following the first and so on with more parts. After the last part is put in, the end time is displayed in a cell.

I have failed at making a code to arrange a list of say 20 parts to make the shortest possible end time. Currently the part numbers are manually rearranges up and down rows until a reasonably low time is reached.

Comment: you have to maybe put a link to a picture of your sheet or, better still, upload it and share the link. What you are trying to do seems like CPM/PERT. We need to see your formulas to understand what's really happening

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to understand what it is you're doing.  Needs at least a screenshot or two and a more-detailed explanation of how you optimize the outcome.

Comment: This sounds like an NP-hard problem, but it may be possible to use Excel's built in solver functionality to do what you are asking.  We need more info.

Comment: perhaps you could provide us with an example, or a portion of your code to get the purpose of your quest.

Comment: You need to add details. You are immersed in the particulars of your problem so you know what you are talking about. We don't. Based on the little that you said, I suspect that @AAA is correct and you are in effect trying to implement CPM. If that is all that it is, the basic algorithm is fairly straightforward to implement. It is one of the few combinatorial optimization problems which is *not* NP-hard.

Comment: [Here's a guide to implementing CPM/PERT in a spreadsheet](http://www.generalinformatics.com/EST581/PERT_by_LP.pdf)